# Is it possible on Cider to eval on a repl and print as a comment every evaluation on a buffer?

Tags: repl, cider

If I want to demonstrate something, is it possible that I can run a command on cider and it prints after each line the result of evaluating that line ?

```
(def xx {:a "a" :b "b"})
(:a xx)
(:c xx [])
```

And, after running (something similar to):

```
(def xx {:a "a" :b "b"}) ; => #'ns-name.playground/xx
(:a xx) ; => "a"
(:c xx "nothing") ; => "nothing"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.
`C-u C-x C-e` eval-last-sexp-and-insert , evaluates the last sexp and inserts it at point.
or:
in the cider-eval menu : eval-last-sexp-and-pretty-print-comment 
insert the output as a comment in the following line like so:

```
(def xx {:a "a" :b "b"}) 
;; => #'ns-name.playground/xx
(:a xx)  
;; => "a"
(:c xx "nothing") 
;; => "nothing"
```

Comment: `cider-pprint-eval-last-sexp-to-comment` nowadays

Comment: Its `cider-pprint-eval-last-sexp-to-comment` or `C-c C-v C-f C-c C-e`.